# Convolution between impulse response

Tags: convolution, control-theory

I read a paper, and am confused about the following:

Suppose $W$ is an operator with impulse response (IR) $w$. And suppose $w^n$ is the IR of $W^n$.

My question is the following:

[image]

It is $w^n(T)*w(T)$ from the right hand side. How could I show it is equal to the left hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If systems $A$ and $B$ have impulse responses $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, then the cascaded system $AB$ has impulse response $a(t) * b(t)$. This is a pretty basic fact in linear system theory.

The system $W^{n+1} = WW^n$ is simply the system $W^n$ cascaded with the system for $W$.

So the impulse response for the cascaded system $W^{n+1} = WW^n$ is simply the convolution of the impulse response of $W^n$ with the impulse response of $W$, i.e. $w^{(n+1)}(T) =  w(T) * w^{(n)}(T)$.